# Scanf in C programming

Tags: c, input, scanf

how can I get just char, not numbers with scanf.

exaple:
input:"2827h829k90157"
output:"h k"

please do not use for,while and if&else .

Comment: `char c1, c2; scanf("%*d%c%*d%c", &c1, &c2);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input specifier `%d` reads numbers and stop at a non-number character.

Adding `*`, `%*d` reads numbers like `%d` and drop that instead of storing to the place specified via the argument.

Therefore, the pair of input and output can be achieved by:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    char c1, c2;
    scanf("%*d%c%*d%c", &c1, &c2) == 2 || (exit(1), 0);
    printf("%c %c\n", c1, c2);
    return 0;
}
```

[demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/IfBM5TwPtTs82Usi)

Using `if` is banned, so I used the short-circuit evaluation of `||` operator to do input check and exiting when the reading fails.

The return type of `exit()` is `void` and it cannot be used with `||` operator, so I added `, 0` to overcome this.

Comment: The construction with the || operator looks suspicious to me. I understand that it evaluates the second arg only if scanf returns something different from 0 in most implementations but what if optimization is turned off or another compiler is used which evaluates both scanf and exit?

Comment: @pqans Doing short-circuit evaluation is defined in the specification. [N1570](http://chimera.roma1.infn.it/SP/COMMON/iso-iec-9899-1990.pdf) 6.5.14 says "Unlike the bitwise | operator, the || operator guarantees left-to-right evaluation; if the second operand is evaluated, there is a sequence point between the evaluations of the first and second operands. If the first operand compares unequal to 0, the second operand is not evaluated." Some non-standard or buggy compilers may not follow this though, but I don't think you should consider this.